# Restoring terminal settings on exit

Tags: haskell, terminal, resource-cleanup

Using [the `terminal` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/terminal-0.2.0.0), my code basically looks like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = withTerminal $ runTerminalT $ do
    eraseInDisplay EraseAll
    hideCursor
    setAutoWrap False

    forever $ do
        calculate
        updateScreen
```

If the user exits this program with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, the terminal settings (in this concrete case, the hidden cursor) remain. I am looking for a lightweight way to **restore the terminal settings as they were before running the program**. By lightweight, I mean something that I can just wrap around the whole `runTerminalT` shebang, instead of having to manually call `checkInterrupt` at various parts of my code etc.

Comment: Bypassing the Haskell layer, dropping closer to the OS layer... At least in Unix/Posixy system, I think you need to have the Ctrl-C handler (catching SIGINT) and perform the required terminal setting restorations therein. Thinking purely on the POSIX level, this is not much code, but I am not able to recommend any fancy Haskell library to use or an appropriate monady way to approach this.

Comment: Sometimes it's best not to do anything fancy.  I think you can just [`installHandler`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Signals.html#v:installHandler) once and be done with it?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to mess around with POSIX signals to do something like Daniel Wagner's answer. `Control.Exception` has everything you need.

```hs
import Control.Exception (handleJust, AsyncException (UserInterrupt))
import Control.Monad (guard)
import System.Exit (exitWith, ExitCode (ExitFailure))

main = withTerminal $ \term ->
  handleJust
         (guard . (== UserInterrupt))
         (\ ~() -> do
           resetTerminalOrWhatever term
           exitWith (ExitFailure 1)) $
         ...
```

You may actually want something broader than that, since you probably want to reset the terminal on *any* abnormal termination:

```hs
main = withTerminal $ \term -> ... `onException` resetTerminalOrWhatever term
```

Note that this second version will be activated by a call to `exitWith` as well. If that's not desired, then you could catch/rethrow manually and refrain from resetting the terminal on `ExitSuccess`.

---

Note that `withTerminal` can actually operate within a more general context than just `IO`, but it always requires a `MonadMask` constraint, which should be sufficient for this general approach.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested to know for sure whether this works out right, but I guess you would just install a signal handler that does your cleanup, then exits just like the default one would.

```
import System.Exit
import System.Posix.Signals

main = do
    installHandler sigINT Nothing . Catch $ do
        resetTerminalOrWhatever
        exitWith (ExitFailure 1)
    withTerminal $ {- ... -}
```

The signals module is available from the [`unix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Signals.html#v:installHandler) package.

If you're paranoid, you could check what the old handler was and try to incorporate it into yours:

```
main = do
    mfix $ \oldHandler ->
        installHandler sigINT Nothing . CatchInfo $ \si -> case oldHandler of
            Default -> reset >> exit
            Ignore -> reset >> exit
            Catch act -> reset >> act
            CatchOnce act -> reset >> act >> exit
            CatchInfo f -> reset >> f si
            CatchInfoOnce f -> reset >> f si >> exit
    withTerminal $ {- ... -}
```

...or something like that.

Comment: Why would you need to install a signal handler? `SIGINT` raises a Haskell exception; just `catch` it.

Comment: @dfeuer Sounds like you've got a competing answer up your sleeve! I encourage you to post it.

Comment: Posted. I had refrained from posting anything because I don't know anything about actually resetting the terminal, but I believe my approach to `SIGINT` is a lot simpler (and more portable) than yours.

Comment: I think you need to install the handler under `withTerminal` where you have access to the terminal to reset it.